# What proportion of closed questions get deleted?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

What proportion of closed questions get deleted, other than by their author?

I'm interested for two reasons:

1. If questions that aren't spam or trolling aren't deleted, then it'd mean that if my first [Happy Feet question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4917/what-counter-words-are-used-by-animals-for-humans) got closed, then I'd have the consolation of it being the second most upvoted closed question, behind [What are good sources for streaming Japanese language television?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-good-sources-for-streaming-japanese-language-television)
2. I'd like to be able to see what questions get closed in practice (as opposed to what's stated in the FAQ). If most questions that are closed get deleted, then the closed questions that aren't deleted may not be representative of all closed questions.

Note: this isn't a complaint about a question receiving votes to close. It is merely a request for information from someone who lacks 10K privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular reason practice would not follow theory, where post deletion policy is concerned. The FAQ is however far from exhaustive on any topic and you will be better server reading through SO meta (or JLU meta), if you really want to get all the information on any such topic.

Closed questions that offer absolutely no value (neither linking to a related question, nor particularly useful example of questions that should not be posted) are eventually deleted. Particularly strings of heavily downvoted questions that clutter the feed and detract from actual questions.

Altogether, deletion of questions is extremely rare. We are talking at most 5 or 6 questions in so many months...

So to answer your main concern: your question, even if it was eventually closed, would fall very short of the above criteria, so there is little chance anybody would attempt to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

[The system deletes some of the old questions without answers from time to time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81887/what-happens-to-unanswered-questions-from-deleted-accounts/82408#82408).  Closed questions often have no answers and therefore often satisfy the criteria for automatic deletion.  Therefore, as you suspect, the closed questions that are not deleted are not representative of all closed questions.